# Excel doesn't sort columns to the right of a blank column

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

If you try to sort on a column when there is a blank column in the spreadsheet, only the columns to the left of the blank column will be sorted.

How can this be changed so that all columns are sorted regardless of whether there are any blank columns?

Comment: You are definitely committed some mistake, otherwise Excel Sorts **Column to the both Right & Left**. Or  possibly you are unable to explain the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

- Select all data, including empty columns, then sort.
- remove empty columns before sorting.
- Select all data, insert a table. Now the empty column will have a column name and will be part of the table. Sort.

Comment: Variant on the first option: select all data, including empty columns, then filter. Now it's two clicks whenever you want to sort: the dropdown arrow that has now appeared, then your choice of sort direction.

Comment: @MathieuK. I assume with "filter" you mean "click the Autofilter command in the ribbon"? Just be careful: when the data does not have a header row, that will transform the first row of data into headers, which may not be desired. Inserting a table will prompt if the data has headers and add them without data loss.

Comment: Yes, except that in my version (2013) it's called Filter, not Autofilter. I've noticed that behaviour too; it's unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Here how it did this.
I used a tool to insert the text character indicator of single quotation mark at the beginning of all cells then excel doesn't see them as empty cells.

The same ASAP tools can then be used to convert numbers back to number if needed.

Comment: Changing the contents of the cells seems like it creates a lot of extra work (and modifies the spreadsheet), when there are a number of solutions that don't require it.